# Prevent the disappearance of the results when typing with the remote option

Tags: jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I noticed a very annoying thing when I search with typeahead.js results with remote, in that while I'm writing, each letter run the refresh of the results, however, in the time that the results should arrive from the server, the previous results disappear, and this is very annoying!

There is no way to ensure that you perform a refresh of the results only when the new results are already available?

Here is a simple example of what I'm saying [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ND8W/6/).

```
$('#movies').typeahead({
    displayKey: 'value',
    header: '<b>Movie suggestions...</b>',
    limit: 10,
    minLength: 2,
    remote: {
        url : 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%QUERY&api_key=470fd2ec8853e25d2f8d86f685d2270e',
        filter: function (parsedResponse) {               
            retval = [];
            debugger;
            for (var i = 0;  i < parsedResponse.results.length;  i++) {
                retval.push({
                    value: parsedResponse.results[i].original_title,
                    tokens: [parsedResponse.results[i].original_title]
                });
            }
            return retval;
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }
});
```

Try to write as "aliens", each letter written disappears around the box with the results.